# how to use jq to flatten nested keys in the json

Tags: json, command-line, nested, key, jq

I am currently trying to process below json using jq commandline

```
cat api-docs.json  | jq '.paths'

{
...
...

  "paths": {
    "/pets": {
         "get": {
...
...
        "post": {
...
...
    "/pets/{petId}": {
         "get": {
...
```

https://jqplay.org/s/GV2zMjbCWK

I need a flattened info from swagger spec above

```
[ "GET /pets", "POST /pets", "GET /pets/{petId}" ]
```

is this even possible with `jq` command ?

with below I get each value independently

```
.paths|{k:keys,v:map(keys)}
```

But what I need is a way to combine keys at nested level to get above result i.e array of  "METHOD /PATH"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following filter produces the results you want, as shown below:

```
.paths
| to_entries
| map( .key as $path
       | ( .value | to_entries[]
           | if .key == "get" then "GET"
             elif .key == "post" then "POST" 
             else empty end ) as $verb
       | $verb + " " + $path )
```

Output:

```
[
  "GET /pets",
  "POST /pets",
  "GET /pets/{petId}"
]
```

You may want to include more "verbs", or handle the verbs programmatically, e.g.

```
.paths
| to_entries
| map(( .value | to_entries[] | .key | ascii_upcase ) + " " + .key)
```

#### Discussion

The key to the solution here is `to_entries`, which produces an array of objects of the form {"key": _, "value": _ }.  Apart from `map`, which here saves having to unpack the array and then repack it, the rest is syntax :-)

Comment: cool , whats difference between to_entries and to_entries[] ?

Comment: `to_entries` produces an array whereas `to_entries[]` produces a stream of JSON entities. `foo[]` is shorthand for `foo | .[]`